# Replace line in XML doc with wildcard

Tags: xml, powershell

I am able to replace a line in a xml document using the following simple code. This works fine when I know the prior value, however I will not know that value and I am having trouble using a wildcard.

For example, this works fine:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\ScriptData.xml"
foreach($file in $files) { 
  (Get-Content $file.fullname) -replace '<Variable Name="%%modelID%%" Value="hello" />', '<Variable Name="%%modelID%%" Value="world" />' |
    Set-Content $file.fullname
}
```

However, when I introduce a wildcard the code does not work, although there is no error:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\ScriptData.xml"
foreach($file in $files) { 
  (Get-Content $file.fullname) -replace '<Variable Name="%%modelID%%" Value="*" />', '<Variable Name="%%modelID%%" Value="world" />' |
    Set-Content $file.fullname
}
```

I think I need to adjust the quotations or use an escape, but nothing I have tried works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-replace command expects regular expression pattern.
Use `.*?` to match any string

```
-replace '<Variable Name="%%modelID%%" Value=".*?" />'
```